# how to merge 2 files with diff contents as json objects

Tags: c#, python-3.x, git, gitlab, merge-file

[image]

I'm trying to merge these two file contents into a new file. I already have the left and rights contents as JSON objects with line numbers and line content.

For instance, I want to select the left part and leave the right part in a new file after the merge. Since the line numbers are different. How are we going to add the left content from the 214th line?

All I want is a final JSON object capturing merge decisions with line numbers. Once I get the merge JSON. I'll use any programming language to create a new file and these changes.

NOTE: When Merging, I'm taking the right file as the main reference. I'll take a copy of the right file and add left contents as and when selected.

Comment: I don't see any JSON in the above screenshot. How does the JSON come in to this picture? All I see is XML.

What have you tried so far?

Comment: The file contents don't matter. Although that is an xml file, that difference is maintained in a json file with line number and content of the line. { left_content: [{line_number: 202, line: "asdfhjasdf" } ]......

Answer (score 1):

As [Aleksey Tsalolikhin commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61142755/how-to-merge-2-files-with-diff-contents-as-json-objects#comment108171112_61142755), what you're showing is XML, not JSON (as encoded into text).  That's not such a big deal: both just provide means of encoding tree-structured data.

Git does not understand any of this.  Git's merge code treats files as *lines* (of text).  That's OK, since you plan to do the merge yourself (with code or manually or whatever).

Note that diffing or merging tree-structured data, regardless of its encoding, is inherently complex.  It should not use line numbers.  It probably *should* see if subtrees match, and if so, consider them moved, even if they have changed depth.

If you've done the merge yourself, and the result should be encoded in text, encode it in text and insert it where it goes and give Git the result as a text file.  All `git merge` needs is the final *text* file.  The merge's *inputs* were three text files—one from the merge base commit, the second from the current commit, and the third from the other commit being merged—and what Git needs is a new *text* file.

So take your merge result, encode it as text, and you're basically done: write it to the appropriate file (or appropriate portion of the appropriate file) and tell Git *this is the correct result of the merge*.  In other words, write out the result and run `git add path/to/file`.

> NOTE: When Merging, I'm taking the right file as the main reference. I'll take a copy of the right file and add left contents as and when selected.

There are *three* inputs to a merge.  There isn't "left and right": there are *merge base*, *ours*, and *theirs*.  The delta from base to ours represents what we changed.  The delta from base to theirs represents what they changed.  Your job is to *combine these changes*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm comparing two random files with no-index. (git --no-index file1 file2) and the unified output I get is analyzed and converted to a JSON structure. 
{ { left_content : [{linenumber: "202", line: "jkhfkajsdfh", changeType: "ADDED"}], right_content : [{linenumber: "215", line: "hkajsdfhkajs", changeType: "ADDED"}] })

I want to merge the left and right content. I know this is a weird approach to calculate the difference and merge two files. If any better approach is available to find diffs and merge them. Please do share them.

Comment: Taking one diff and doing something with it is not *merging*, it's just *applying a diff*. Please don't call it *merging*....

Comment: okay. I will call it as applying a diff. I meant I will create a copy of the right side and apply diffs and the final output is a merged one of both. The left or right version is selected from UI I provide later.